# Date function displays wrong date

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to display date inside a table using the below code.
Now, suppose the date to display is 12 Dec 2013, then echo $date1 displays the date as 2013-12-12. But `echo date("j-F-Y", strtotime($date1));` displays the date as 31 Dec 1969.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>    
<tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td><?php $date1='{{posted}}';echo $date1 ;echo date("j-F-Y", strtotime($date1));?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>
```

What should I do to display the date that is printed in $date1. Why is the date() failing to display the correct date.

Comment: Tag the rdms `mysql` I guess !!

Comment: where should I tag mysql here

Comment: What does strototime give back really? Maybe false or -1?

Comment: Check here http://ideone.com/deW8WF

Comment: @Roopendra I know what you are telling...but it does not work for me

Comment: @user3004356 : as you mention in your question `echo $date1 displays the date as 2013-12-12`. so same thing I was tried. might be something else wrong.

Comment: See what Peter said is right...it is returning false

Answer (score 1):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) return either false or -1 (prior to 5.1) on failure. That timestamp (0) will equal to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT. With a timezone somewhere in the 'minus something' that would equal to a date of 1969-12-31.

So `strtotime($date1)` couldn't parse `$date1`. Are you sure it equals to the string `'2013-12-12'`? Use `var_dump($date1);` to verify.

It could be an object with a `__toString()`-method, so an echo would show the result of that method, not the actual value of `$date1` itself.

Comment: When I did var_dump($date1), I got `string(10) "2013-12-12"`

Comment: That's weird, what does `var_dump(strtotime($date1))` say?

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime($date1))` returns bool(false)

Comment: So what should I do now, when it is false. Pls guide me

Comment: Can you add a `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam')` somewhere before that code and try again, maybe that solves it. For a list of available timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: I used `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`. Still doesn't work

Comment: What happens if you change `stsrtotime($date1)` to `strototime('2013-12-12')`; Also returns false or does that works? Maybe the dash in your `$date1` is one of the UTF8-special dashes

Comment: Works fine for `strototime('2013-12-12');`. Should I insert inverted commas

Comment: Ah, now I see it. You have a template-system. `$date1` will be '{{posted}}', that will be given to strtotime, and that will fail. All the var_dumps and echo's of `$date1` worked because the output is parsed by your template-engine (and '{{posted}}' is also 10 chars, same as the date). Find a way to get the real value of the date, and not just the template-parseable string.

Answer (score -1):

The strtotime method returns something else for 2013-12-12 than you expect. See here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php#100144

> The best way to compensate for this is by modifying your joining
>   characters. Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, a
>   dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO
>   Y.M.D.

So you have to use another format at strtotime. That also explains why date returns a value one day before the first of January 1970.

Comment: According to the PHP-manual itself (and not the comments): `To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates`